# Error in Angular: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'datetime' since it isn't a known property of 'time'

Tags: angular, datetime, time

I want to add attribute `datetime` to `time` element in Angular:

```html
<time 
class="updated" 
[datetime]="post.modified_gmt">
{{ post.modified_gmt | date: 'short'}}
</time>
```

But get next error:

> Error: Template parse errors: 
>   Can't bind to 'datetime' since it isn't a known property of 'time'. 
>   (" class="entry-date published">{{ post.date_gmt | date: 'short'}}

What the solution? Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show time component?

Comment: have you defined `datetime` as `@Input() datetime;` inside component for `time`  ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 Actually, 'time' is html element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time

Answer (score 20):

correct the lowercase `[dateTime]`.

```
<time 
  class="updated" 
  [dateTime]="post.modified_gmt">

{{ post.modified_gmt | date: 'short'}}

</time>
```

Have try.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is absolutely correct

Answer (score 5):

You are using template binding *syntax* on a *non-component* element.

When you write `[datetime]="..."` it tells Angular to bind the expression to an `@Input()` named `datetime`, but the `<time>` tag is not part of any component or directive.

You have to use attribute syntax if you want Angular to assign the value to the element's attributes.

```
<time class="updated" [attr.datetime]="post.modified_gmt">{{ post.modified_gmt | date: 'short'}}</time>
```

Normally, you can assign expressions to attributes using `{{ }}` syntax. Such as `<time datetime="{{post.modified_gmt}}"></time>`, but this only works if Angular has the attribute in it's *whitelist* of supported HTML elements and attributes. It appears `datetime` is not supported.

You can suppress the error message by adding `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to your `@NgModule()` but this only hides the error. The expression will still not set the `datetime` attribute.

There is a way to add your own custom schemas using `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and tell Angular to support the `datetime` attribute, but I don't know how it works and don't think it's worth it. Just use `[attr.datetime]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `datetime` as `@Input() datetime;` inside component for time as below :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'time',
  template: `your template goes here`
})
export class TimeComponent {
  @Input() datetime: any;
}
```

Comment: Actually, 'time' is html element: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time

Comment: have you tried to check with `[attr.datetime]="post.modified_gmt"` ?